# Dozer mapping on objects to

Tags: java, dozer

i have an two seperate objects to map:

```
Class A {
    List<AA> listAA;
    // get set methods...
}

Class B{
    C objectC = new C();
    // get set methods...
}

Class C{
    List<CC> listCC;
    // get set methods...
}

Class AA{
    String aa;
    // get set methods...
}

Class CC{
     String cc;
    // get set methods...
}
```

So i want to map listAA to listCC that inside of C. With C has B as a parents.

I try describing it as data structure:

```
a.listAA -> b.c.listCC
```

So far i've tried:

```
<mappings>
    <mapping>
        <class-a>mypackages.A</class-a>
        <class-b>mypackages.B</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>listAA</a>
            <b>objectC.listCC</b>
            <b-hint>mypackages.CC</b-hint>
        <field>
    </mapping>

    <mapping>
        <class-a>mypackages.AA</class-a>
        <class-b>mypackages.CC</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>aa</a>
            <b>cc</b>
        <field>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

I think is that dozer didn't know

```
objectC.listCC
```

as an list with in Object. Instead tried to find attributes that called 'objectC.listCC'.

And it throws

```
 NullPointerException
    at org.dozer.util.ReflectionsUtils.invoke(ReflectionsUtils)
    ...
```

Does any one knows to how to solve this.

Regards

Ivan

PS: I hope i was describeing it clearly

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace? It could be useful for understanding what's happening inside your code.

Comment: Maybe because you're using `listA` and `listC` in the XML instead of `listAA` and `listCC`

Comment: @Vasan yeah, you are right. I mistype on this problem description. But in my Code u put the right code

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to go out and forget for searching the answers and come again with a fresh head. 
I extend the mapping configuration into three parts. Because dozer are not able to map object to a grand child object. So you have to do like chain mapping:

```
 <mappings>
    <mapping>
        <class-a>mypackages.A</class-a>
        <class-b>mypackages.B</class-b>
        <field map-id="listAAToObjectC">
            <a>listAA</a>
            <b>objectC</b>
            <b-hint>mypackages.C</b-hint>
        <field>
    </mapping>
    <mapping map-id="listAAToObjectC">
        <class-a>mypackages.A</class-a>
        <class-b>mypackages.C</class-b>
        <field map-id="listToList">
            <a>listAA/a>
            <b>listCC</b>
        <field>
    </mapping>
    <mapping map-id="listToList">
        <class-a>mypackages.AA</class-a>
        <class-b>mypackages.CC</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>aa</a>
            <b>cc</b>
        <field>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```